# Column name sql isnull() clause where

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I can't make a where clause on the IdCell column but i can do an "order by".

SQL server say error on the column name

```
    select 
    *, (ISNULL(Table_Adresses.IdCellule, Table_Clients.IdCellule)) as IdCell
    from Table_Tickets 
    left join Table_Postes on Table_Postes.IdPoste = Table_Tickets.IdPoste
    left join Table_Adresses on Table_Adresses.IdAdresse = Table_Postes.IdAdressePhysique
    left join Table_Clients on Table_Clients.IdClient = Table_Tickets.IdClient
    where idtypeticket=2 and 
    isnull(bcloture,0)=0 and 
    IdCell =4 --problem here
    order by IdCell
```

Why can't i make a where on IdCell ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use your aliased column in this way, you'll need to do:

```
and (ISNULL(Table_Adresses.IdCellule, Table_Clients.IdCellule)) = 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Although SQL (the language) forces you to structure your queries in the order `SELECT-FROM-WHERE-ORDER BY`, it is (effectively) gets executed in the order `FROM-WHERE-SELECT-ORDER BY`. This is why you can use your `AS` clause ("column alias") `IdCell` in the `ORDER BY` clause but not in the `WHERE` clause i.e. `IdCell` is not in scope for the `WHERE` clause because it only comes into existence later.

Answer (score 0):

```
   select 
    *, (ISNULL(Table_Adresses.IdCellule, Table_Clients.IdCellule)) as IdCell
    from Table_Tickets 
    left join Table_Postes on Table_Postes.IdPoste = Table_Tickets.IdPoste
    left join Table_Adresses on Table_Adresses.IdAdresse = Table_Postes.IdAdressePhysique
    left join Table_Clients on Table_Clients.IdClient = Table_Tickets.IdClient
    where idtypeticket=2 and 
    isnull(bcloture,0)=0 and 
    (ISNULL(Table_Adresses.IdCellule, Table_Clients.IdCellule)) =4 
    order by IdCell
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    *, (ISNULL(Table_Adresses.IdCellule, Table_Clients.IdCellule)) as IdCell
    from Table_Tickets 
    left join Table_Postes on Table_Postes.IdPoste = Table_Tickets.IdPoste
    left join Table_Adresses on Table_Adresses.IdAdresse = Table_Postes.IdAdressePhysique
    left join Table_Clients on Table_Clients.IdClient = Table_Tickets.IdClient
    where idtypeticket=2 and 
    bcloture is null and
    (ISNULL(Table_Adresses.IdCellule, Table_Clients.IdCellule)) = 4 
    order by IdCell
```